# Android How to call method on Activity from JavascriptInterface

Tags: android, methods

I have a webview which has HTML with a link calling Android.closeRegForm()
in WebAppInterface i have a method

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void closeRegForm() {
        ((MainActivity)mContext).closeRegForm();
    }
```

which must call method closeRegForm on MainActivity, but I am getting this error.

```
09-10 12:54:50.134: E/Web Console(1171): Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject. at http://example.com/aaa.php:1
```

when I change this method to

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void closeRegForm() {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "blabla", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

it shows "blabla" toast. Why I cannot call method on mainactivity?

Comment: "Uncaught Error" suggests there's an exception of some sort. Surround with try/catch and log it.

Comment: thanks,
I got this error,
09-10 13:11:03.526: D/qwe(1242): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. I know what to do whit it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the function of different name in MainActivity

```
public void closeRegForm1() {
    //Anything
}
```

Note: This should be public

And then call as

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void closeRegForm() {
    ((MainActivity)mContext).closeRegForm1();
}
```